# Adding Icon to JButton without changing its size

Tags: java, icons, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I am trying to add an `Icon` to the `JButton`
When I try to do this my Layout Manager (I use `GridBagLayout`) resizes the button and makes it larger by the size of the icon.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `resizes the button and makes it larger by the size of the icon.` - well that makes sense to me. If you add an Icon the button should get bigger. Why is this unreasonable? Why don't you specify a reasonable requirement. Do you want the Icon to be truncated? Do you want it to be scaled? Do you want it to be ignored?

Comment: I ma making a Minesweeper game and I would like this to be ignored.

Comment: Well it can't be ignored. Create an Icon for the "normal" state. Create an Icon for the "clicked" state. The size of the Icons should be the same. Then in your logic when you change Icons the size of your button will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try *JButton#setPreferedSize(...)*

Or you could override the *paintComponent* method:

```
JButton testButton = new JButton() {
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
   }
};
```

If you want to do this with multiple buttons, it would be better to make a class for it ofcourse, something like:

```
class ImageButton extends JButton {             
    private final Image image;                  

    public ImageButton(Image image) {           
        this.image = image;                     
    }                                           

    @Override                                   
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
        super.paintComponent(g);                
        //drawing logic here                          
    }                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Do these things:

1. Resize your image to fit the button with an image manipulating program.
2. use setMininumSize() and set the minimum size you want.

This will probably fix your problem.